# Extract phone numbers with hyphen using Python regex

Tags: python, regex

I have an address string like this

```
addr_str = "No 123 4th St, 5th Ave NYC\n\tPhone: 9938483902"
```

Currently, I'm using regex to extract `phone number` from the end of the string like this:

```
phone = re.search(r'\d+$', addr_str)
print phone.group()
```

I just realized that there are some phone numbers like:

```
040-38488993 
3888-32888222 
01854-29924402
```

How can I alter this regex to get the numbers before the hyphen? Any help?

Please note that the number of digits before the hyphen vary erratically and I also have numbers without any hyphens which I need as well.

Comment: "Phone: " will always be at start of phone?. In fact you could have a lots of data in this string, and basically its better to have some key words for info to parse, or to store data in dictionary or smth

Comment: @Dmitry.Samborskyi, do you mean will phone number always be at the end of the string? Yes, it will.

Comment: The point is that you can easily find the position of "Phone: " and discard using regex.

Comment: Well if you want *all numbers or dashes at the end of the string*, why not `r'[\d\-]+$'`?

Comment: Do you need to keep the hyphen in the result or do you only want the numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could have your digit pattern to include optional minus sign and expect the group to be repeated 1 or 2 times.

```
phone = re.search(r'(\d+-?){1,2}$', addr_str)
```

Answer (score 2):

Just put `-`, `\d` inside a char class.

```
phone = re.search(r'[\d-]+$', addr_str)
```

If the phonenumber startswith with a optional `+` then you may try this,

```
phone = re.search(r'\+?\d+(?-\d+)*$', addr_str)
```

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think it was so simple :)

Answer (score 1):

```
phone = re.search(r'\d[\d-]+\d$', addr_str)
```

You can simply modify your regex to this.If there is always a possiblity of only   1 `-` use

```
phone = re.search(r'\d+-\d+$', addr_str)
```

Answer (score 1):

In case your string always contains `Phone:` with the phone number following it at the end, you do not need the regex. Also, note that `1-800-MALL` is also a valid phone number.

I suggest [this](http://ideone.com/vDKnpA):

```
addr_str = "No 123 4th St, 5th Ave NYC\n\tPhone: 1-800-MALL"
idx = addr_str.find("Phone: ")
if idx > -1:
    print addr_str[idx+7:]
else:
    print addr_str
```

Or, in case regex is still preferable, [another solution](http://ideone.com/85j94u):

```
import re
addr_str = "No 123 4th St, 5th Ave NYC\n\tPhone: 1-800-MALL"
print re.search(r"Phone:\s*(.*)$", addr_str).group(1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to allow only one hyphenated section then you can do this using an optional group

```
((\d+-)?\d+)$
```

Demonstration: https://regex101.com/r/wV6zP7/1

For example, this will match "0123-456789" but not "0123-456-789".

Answer (score 0):

If you always have a space before the phone number, why not simply:

```
phone = addr_str[addr_str.rfind(' ') + 1:]
```